# What exactly is EventType in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

As the question title suggests, What exactly EventType is doing in Android Java?
I came across an Android development tutorial about XML Parsing, it seems to have a crucial part in that.
I never really understand what it does and why does it help on XML Parsing.
And please give the explanation in simple English because i'm not a native English speaker lol, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventType is essentially a block of content in an XML document that contains some sort of significant data. So that could be a tag, some text, etc. The [Android XmlPullParser docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) explain it this way:

> The current event state of the parser can be determined by calling the
>   getEventType() method. Initially, the parser is in the START_DOCUMENT
>   state.
>
> The method next() advances the parser to the next event. The int value
>   returned from next determines the current parser state and is
>   identical to the value returned from following calls to getEventType
>   ().

So usually the way XML parsers work, is you traverse the document looking for "events," which are points of interest. So in other words, you want to keep going through the document character by character until you see something of interest, like a start tag or something similar. When you find an event, you want the parser to stop and identify that event for you so you know what to do with it. The process usually looks something like this:

```
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
      System.out.println("Start document");
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
      System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
      System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
      System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
    }
    eventType = xpp.next();
}
System.out.println("End document");
```

So in this code, we allow the parser to traverse the document, stopping on each "event" (point of interest). We then check the event, and if it's something like a tag, we read the name of the tag -- if it's text, we read the text, etc. So basically you find an "event" you want, then you read the content that the event contains.

But essentially, an event is just your place in the document...it could be the document start, the document end, a tag, some text, etc. Event type is just differentiating between the different types we can expect. The various event types are usually stored in static constants, similar to the way `XmlPullParser` works. So there is a list of events you can expect, and you just have to check to see which one you've arrived at.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really did help me out a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!